# How to remove hover from button? Material UI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I put the mouse on the login button, the background color of the button doesn't stay white. How do I stay white? Help me please. I tried that but it didn't work.

```
<Button
  key={item}
  sx={{
   color: "secondary.contrastText",
   backgroundColor: "secondary.light",
   "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "transparent"
    }
   }}
```

[Code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/menu-responsivo-kmxo30?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set `backgroundColor` to `transparent`, that means it will inherit it from the background element. Your background element (i.e., navbar) is orange. That's why the button becomes orange on hover. You need to set `backgroundColor` to `white`.

Try the following:

```
<Button
  key={item}
  sx={{
    color: "secondary.contrastText",
    backgroundColor: "secondary.light",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "white"
    }
  }}
  size="medium"
>
  {item}
</Button>
```

See the [forked snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/menu-responsivo-forked-7y84zj).